# programatically Align views in android Grid Layout

Tags: android

I have three different types of views (View 1 ,View 2 , View 3). I have a viewSupplierClass which returns these views in any order and any number. ( Eg: View 1 , View 2 ,View 2 ,View 2 , View 3 , View 1 ,View 3 , View 2 ,...). Now I need to arrange them in Activity in the order that i get and without leaving spaces.

I choose to do this with gridLayout and categorized these view as a matrix (i,e View 1 - 2X2, View 2- 1X2, View 3 -1X1 ). But my output is not as expected.I get spaces in between as the views are not of same size.
Can Someone help me with a better solution or point to what my mistake is.

Here is my code and the output :

Activity

```
private void addViews() {
        for (position = 0; position <= totalItems; position++) {
            LayoutSupplierClass layout = new LayoutSupplierClass(this, position);
            gridLayout.addView(layout);
        }
    }
```

xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/text">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="2"
                tools:context=".GridXMLActivity" >
            </GridLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/customize"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/gridLayout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/customize " />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```